# React/JSX not running onClick/fetch function in form instead posting to "/"

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to make a form in a react app send a post request to a flask backend. The request is either sent as a GET in the URL (default form behavior) or send as a POST to "proxyaddr/" (bad URL)

Here is the form and function to send the data:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function PaymentForm() {

    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();
    const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState();
    const [payDates, setPayDates] = useState();
    const [isError, setError] = useState(false);

    function errorMsg({hasError}){
        if (hasError)
            return <p>Error occured</p>
    }

    function submitData(data){
        fetch('/get_dates', {method: "post", body: data})
        .then((responce) => {
            const res = responce.formData
            setPayDates(res.get("frequency_dates"))
        })
    }
    function handPaymentForm(e){
        e.preventDefaults();
        alert("ran");
        const form = e.target;
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const jsonData = Object.formEntries(formData);

        try { 
            submitData(jsonData);
        }
        catch(e){
            setError(true);
        }
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment><p className="text-gray-500 font-bold mt-10">Schedule Payments</p>
        <form onSubmit={handPaymentForm}>
            <label>Start Date: <input name="start_date" type="date" onChange={(e)=> setStartDate(e.target.value)}/></label>
            <br/><label>End Date: <input name="end_date" type="date" onChange={(e)=> setEndDate(e.target.value)}/></label>
            <br/><label>
                <select name = "frequency" onChange={(e)=> setFrequency(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="WEEKLY">Weekly</option>
                    <option value="BI-WEEKLY">Bi-Weekly</option>
                    <option value="MONTHLY">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="BI-MONTHLY">Bi-Monthly</option>
                    <option value="QUARTERLY">Quarterly</option>
                    <option value="SEMI-YEARLY">Semi-Yearly</option>
                    <option value="ANNUAL">Annual</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br/><button type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        <errorMsg hasError={isError}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

and here is the flask python file:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import holidays
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

term_dict = {
    "WEEKLY": 7,
    "BI-WEEKLY": 14,
    "MONTHLY": 30,
    "BI-MONTHLY": 60,
    "QUARTERLY": 90,
    "SEMI-YEARLY": 180,
    "ANNUAL": 365
}


@app.get('/test_endpoint')
def test_endpoint():
    return {"members" : ["1", "2","3"]}

@app.post('/get_dates')
def frequency_dates():
    data = request.get_json()
    print("hello")
    start_date = datetime.strptime(data['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(data['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    term = request.form['term']

    if term not in term_dict:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Bruh invalid term'}), 400

    frequency_dates = []
    delta_days = term_dict[term]
    current_date = start_date

    while current_date <= end_date:
        frequency_dates.append(str(current_date))
        current_date += timedelta(days=delta_days)

    return jsonify({'frequency_dates': frequency_dates}), 200

@app.route('/is_us_holiday', methods=['POST'])
def is_us_holiday():
    input_date = datetime.strptime(request.form['input_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    us_holidays = holidays.US()
    us_holidays = holidays.country_holidays('US')
    nyse_holidays = holidays.NYSE()
    nyse_holidays = holidays.financial_holidays('NYSE')
    is_holiday = input_date in us_holidays or input_date in nyse_holidays

    return jsonify({'is_holiday': is_holiday}), 200

cors = CORS(app, resources={'/*':{'origins': 'http://localhost:3000'}}) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Output from flask (first two are when I tested in with no action="get/post" in the form tag):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2023 12:13:03] "POST /?start_date=&end_date=&frequency=WEEKLY HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2023 12:18:10] "POST /?start_date=&end_date=&frequency=WEEKLY HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2023 12:19:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2023 12:19:45] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Edit: I would like to add I tried adding alert() to if the function was actually running and it appears not to.
This is my first time using stack overflow, I've read plenty of answers over the years but never submitted a question. I apologies if I've missed some important information and am happy to add anything which may be of use. I appreciate any assistance, I'm rather new to web development.

Comment: There's a typo on `e.preventDefaults()`, it should be `e.preventDefault()` with no "s"

Comment: `res.get("frequency_dates")` doesn't look right. You can't just pluck out a property value from the response like that.

Comment: @M.Desjardins this fixed my issue. Thank you so much. I feel stupid.

Comment: and @Andy, thank you for pointing out the other issue, I haven't gotten to that point of debugging yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer for visibility.

In your `handPaymentForm` form submit event handler, there is a typo:

```
e.preventDefaults();
```

The method on the event object is [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) (with no "s"), so the above line should just be `e.preventDefault()` instead.